# How do you enable Visual Basic.NET namespace by default?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I'm coming from C# background and in Visual Studio. The namespace is shown by default but not in Visual Basic. Is there an option to enable namespace to be shown in Visual Studio 2008?

Answer (score 5):

VB.Net has a concept of default namespace for a project.  Any file created in the project which does not contain an explicit namespace will be intsead included in the default namespace.

If you don't like this behavior you can disable it from the project property page (right click on the project and select properties).  Go to the Application tab and clear the Root Namespace text box.  This will force you to provide a namespace for every type you define.