# class procedure call and class reference syntax

Tags: vb.net

I have two questions:

Q1) Lets assume i got Logger class and procedure inside called Log i would like to call it from other class like this, is it possible?:

```
New Logger().Do("myMessage")
```

i tried but the only way i can use is two lines way:

```
 Dim log As Logger = New Logger()
 log.Do("myMessage")
```

Q2) If i do class library reference and put Imports i am still obligated to use long way call, why?:

```
Imports ImportRunner                   'other solution reference i added to this project

Public Class MainProcessRunner

    Public Sub New()
        Dim imp1 As ImportRunner.ImportRunner = New ImportRunner.ImportRunner(Date.Now)
        imp1.RunDaily()
```

Here i am required to use two times:

```
ImportRunner.ImportRunner  -instead of just once
```

Comment: Did you create the Logger class?  You can make the `Do` method `Shared`.  Then you can call it without using New in one line like this:  `Logger.Do("My Message")`

Answer (score 0):

1) For the first question see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20953640/call-instance-method-inline-after-new-statement). Seems it has to be in two lines.

2) For the second question, See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923315/visual-basic-and-a-namespace-issue) :

"Open the Project Properties and click on the Application properties. CLEAR the Root Namespace there."

Comment: Did you (as the last answer) : **Open the Project Properties and click on the Application properties. CLEAR the Root Namespace there.** ?

Comment: this solution works but i always need to keep in mind to  remove root namespace.

Comment: what about first question is there really no way to achieve that as in C# is?

Comment: not good because its simpler annd much more looks good for me in one line.